# file_put_content Resource id #233

Tags: php

```
$data = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

$log = base_path()."/storage/logs/trade.log";

if ( !file_exists ($log) ) {
    $data = fopen($log, "w");
}

file_put_contents($log, $data . PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

I have a page use file_put_contents to record log. when my folder don't exist file, it will auto create the file and add log into it

My problem is when first time auto create file and place content into it. It comes out - Resource id #233

2nd time without crate file will be normal no any problem

anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you understand that `$data` variable is __overwritten__?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) returns a `resource`.

[`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file_put_contents) write your file and converts `$data` into a string (calls `__toString()` on the `resource`).

The second times, the file exists. So, the program doesn't pass into the if-condition and it writes `$data` that contains JSON.

To solve your problem, just remove your `if` block.

Documentation said :

> If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

Comment: If to read a manual for `file_put_contents` there's "If filename does not exist, the file is created", so the `if` clause is __useless__.

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks. It was my first anwser, but I changed it after reading the documentation. But I confused with the "override" sentense. I've updated my anwser.